# What is the best design pattern to read an excel with multiple sheets

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have an excel sheet with a standard format that will have multiple sheets.  I need to read the sheets in Java and convert them to Objects and store in the database. I and currently using the Simple Factory pattern for this. I am reading the sheet name and invoking the corresponding converter objects based on the sheet name. Is this the only way to achieve this or is there a better way. Below is the sample code.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("test.xls"));
        HSSFWorkbook hssfWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        int numberOfSheets = hssfWorkbook.getNumberOfSheets();
        for (int i=0; i<numberOfSheets; i++) {
           HSSFSheet sh =  hssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(i);
           String sname = sh.getSheetName();
           switch (sname) {
               case "Test" : //go to test convertor;
               case "Test1": //go to test1 convertor
           }
        }
```

Comment: You should detail the part "go to test convertor".  It matters.

Comment: Its just setting the values in the file and saving it to the database

Comment: There is no design pattern for reading in Excel worksheets.  I can't help but think that saving worksheets in a database is not a good idea.  More context would be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with the [`strategy design pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

You could have a `ISheetConverter` and multiple implementations defining its own conversion logic.
It'd look something like:

```
@FunctionalInterface
inferface ISheetConverter {
    POJOForSheet convert(SheetStream sheetFromIO);
}
```

Also your existing factory class can return appropriate `ISheetConverter` *class* based on the `sh.getSheetName()` (which will do the conversion later-on).

Comment: The conversion strategy will be the same. The only difference is what it is being converted into. Like the excel sheet with name A needs to be converted to a list of objects of type A. The next sheet with name B needs to be converted to a list of objects of type B.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the **STRATEGY** pattern is the befitting one here.

The complete code goes below (though in C#) but it shall explain the implementation style

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IStrategyManager manager = new StrategyManager(); // this code is added 

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("test.xls"));
        HSSFWorkbook hssfWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        int numberOfSheets = hssfWorkbook.getNumberOfSheets();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSheets; i++)
        {
            HSSFSheet sh = hssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(i);
            String sname = sh.getSheetName();
            manager.Manage(sname); // this code is added 
        }          
    }
}
```

The StrategyManager stores all the converters

```
interface IStrategyManager
{
    void Manage(string sheetName);
}

class StrategyManager : IStrategyManager
{
    private Dictionary<string, IConverter> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, IConverter>();

    public StrategyManager()
    {
     // store converter name & its implementation class name which are one and same
        dictionary.Add("Test", new Test());
        dictionary.Add("Test2", new Test2());
    }

    public void Manage(string sheetName)
    {
        dictionary[sheetName].Convert(sheetName); // magic happens here
    }
}
```

Various type of converter implementation goes below

```
interface IConverter
{
    void Convert(string sheetName);
}

class Test : IConverter
{
    public void Convert(string sheetName)
    {
        /*   conversion logic for test converter  goes here*/
    }
}

class Test2 : IConverter
{
    public void Convert(string sheetName)
    {
        /*   conversion logic for test2 converter  goes here*/
    }
}
```

@user3310115, Hope it helps ,if any clarity needed, please get hold of me.Thanks